# Descargar pdf iPhone e iPad

Tags: ios, iphone

Tengo una aplicativo que abre un iframe a otra página desde donde puedo descargar un PDF.

Desde web (Chrome, Firefox) me lo descarga, desde Android también, pero desde iPhone e iPad, en Firefox y Chrome me abre el pdf dentro del iFrame.

Necesito poder descargarlo.

Alguna idea por que se comporta así en iOS ?

Saludos

Comment: Puedes agregar el código? Y las etiquetas de los lenguajes que usas.

Comment: No es problema de código. Ya que como indico, en navegadores Chrome, Firefox y Edge funciona en Windows. En Android con Firefox y Chrome también. En iPhone e iPad con Safari también. En todos los anteriores muestra ventana para descargar el PDF, pero como digo es en Chrome y Firefox de iPhone e iPad donde no realiza descarga, abre el PDF, por eso pregunto si es problema de estos navegadores en estos dispositivos al estar "capados"